# Obtain historical statistics of contributions in a Git repository (of lines still in use)

Tags: git

Developers make commits, merge branches, overwrite each other's code.  They come in and refactor or add new features.  Code is iterative.

Is there a good git mechanism for finding which developer has the most utilized code in the current branch?

For example:

1. Developer **X** creates 100 lines in a file.
2. Developers **Y** and **Z** each refactor 50 lines of code.

`git blame` for the 100 line file will show developers **Y** and **Z** as the authors of 50 lines of code each.
According to the same *blame*, developer **X** is responsible for 0 lines of code.

However, we know that **X** wrote the original 100 lines. Therefore, I would like to know the contribution of each developer.

Considering the current lines of code still in use: Is there a good `git` mechanism for finding who have contributed the most through the history of such lines?

Comment: What do you mean by "utilized"?

Comment: code that still exists. code that has not be overwritten by another developer.

Comment: So, the most lines of code in whatever version is currently checked out?

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting question! Thanks for asking - it's what I'd also need for my team occasionally.

I came with a quick'n'dirty approximation of what you'd want:

What is needed is author grep over an output of `git blame --line-porcelain`.

```
(for f in `git ls-files`; do git blame --line-porcelain  $f |
   grep 'author '; done) | 
awk '{cnt[$_]++} END {for (x in cnt) print cnt[x],x}' | sort -rn -k1
```

It's not a rocket science nor a speed demon. It's just an aggregation over an output of `git blame` for all repository files, using standard Unix tools. But it shows some neat output..

I checked the numbers; sum of aggregated counters is equal to the sum of line counters for all files returned by `git ls-files`, which is what we expect.

Example for a repository of [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org) language:

```
97037 author José Valim
3151 author Aleksei Magusev
3017 author Alexei Sholik
3003 author James Fish
2837 author Bryan Enders
2677 author Eric Meadows-Jönsson
2667 author eksperimental
1604 author Andrea Leopardi
1109 author Bryan Endersstocker
1073 author Eric Meadows-Jonsson
1058 author Yurii Rashkovskii
901 author Yuki Ito
828 author Rafael Mendonça França
735 author John Warwick
689 author Paulo Almeida
[...]
```

Beware the use of `git blame --line-porcelain` instead of `git blame --incremental`. The latter outputs information in records corresponding to commits, not single lines; so the counting would be wrong.

[*EDIT note*] Whoever looked at the original answer, it contained a bug, which was explained together with a proper solution, and later edited by community to shorten the message.